# passing a vector returned from a function to another function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc4.7

I have a function that returns a vector of strings

```
std::vector<std::string> getNames()
{
std::vector<std::string> names;
names.push_back("one");
return names;
}
```

I have another class with a constructor with the following signature (this is actually from TCLAP):

```
ValuesConstraint(std::vector<T>& allowed);
```

I receive an error if I attempt to do the following

```
ValuesConstraint<std::string> A( getNames() );
```

But not when I do the following

```
std::vector<std::string> v = getNames();
ValuesConstraint<std::string> A( v );
```

This occurs in GCC 4.4.7 but not in VS2010.  The error is as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘TCLAP::ValuesConstraint<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::ValuesConstraint(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)’

note: candidates are: TCLAP::ValuesConstraint<T>::ValuesConstraint(std::vector<T, std::allocator<_CharT> >&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]

note:                 TCLAP::ValuesConstraint<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::ValuesConstraint(const TCLAP::ValuesConstraint<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)
```

Why is this error occurring, and what can I do to pass the return value directly to the constructor?

Comment: `but not in VS2010`, this is due to a compiler extension. Compile with `/W4` and it should warn about it or `/Za` to disable extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this error occurring, and what can I do to pass the return value directly to the constructor?

The constructor of `ValuesConstraint<>` accepts an lvalue (lvalue references to non-`const` can only bind to lvalues), while function call expressions that do not return a reference type are *rvalues*.

lvalue references cannot bind to rvalues, so you cannot pass a temporary to the constructor of `ValuesConstraint<>` (temporaries are rvalues).

If you find the terms *lvalue* and *rvalue* confusing, you can (intuitively) think of lvalues as:

- named variables (actually, identifiers); and/or
- objects (actually, expressions) you can take the address of

They usually denote objects that can be repeatably referenced in a program, with a stable identity, from which it is *not* safe to move implicitly (because they could be referenced later on in a program).

On the contrary, you can see rvalues as:

- unnamed objects like temporaries; and/or
- literals (like `42`, `false`, and `3.14`); and/or
- expressions denoting objects with an "unstable" identity (like the result of `std::move()`), which are about to be moved from

They usually denote objects that *cannot* be repeatably referenced in a program (or objects *you* promised not to reference anymore before reassigning them by explicitly calling `std::move()`) and are, therefore, safe to move from.

Take the above with a grain of salt though - it is just a guideline you can use to build some intuition on what value categories are, and how to tell what is the value category of a certain expression. In formal terms, things are a bit more complicated and the above generalizations are not always correct.

So getting back to your example, in this situation:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = getNames();
//                       ^
//                       Named variable! Can take its address! lvalue!
ValuesConstraint<std::string> A( v );
//                               ^
//                               OK! The constructor accepts an lvalue
//                               reference to non-const, and I am giving
//                               it an lvalue
```

You are passing an lvalue to the constructor and everything works fine. In this situation, on the other hand:

```
ValuesConstraint<std::string> A( getNames() );
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^
//                               getNames() returns a vector by value, this
//                               means a temporary will be constructed as the
//                               return value of the function, and temporaries
//                               are unnamed... so, that's an rvalue!
//                               And the constructor accepts an lvalue reference
//                               to non-const! So this is an ERROR!
```

You are trying to pass an rvalue to a function that accepts an lvalue reference to non-`const` (in other words, it wants a modifiable lvalue). That's illegal, and the compiler complains about it.

> This occurs in GCC 4.4.7 but not in VS2010

That is because VC10 implements a non-conforming compiler extension that allows binding rvalues to lvalue references to non-`const`. Watch out though, this is **not** standard behavior, and if you want to write portable code, you shouldn't rely on it (I'd suggest you not to rely on it anyway, actually).

[As suggested by Jesse Good in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535712/passing-a-vector-returned-from-a-function-to-another-function/17535744#comment25502944_17535712), raise the warning level to 4 in order to get a warning from the compiler and detect situations where you are making use of this non-standard extension.

Comment: Is assigning the value to a named variable prior to passing to the constructor the best way to go?  Or is there some potential modification to the getNames function?

Comment: @denver: It is not simply the best way to go, it is the *only* way to go (if you want to write portable code). Unless, of course, you can change the signature of `ValuesConstraint`'s constructor, but I understood it's not under your control

Comment: `lvalue` comes from "value that can go on the left hand side of an assignment", and `rvalue` comes from "value that can go on the right hand side of an assignment".  Take these origins with a grain of salt: while that is where the term came from, it does not reflect current usage.

Comment: @Yakk: Indeed, which is why I preferred not to mention this (so the OP would not get confused). But you're right, that's where the terms come from.